# Independent or dependent data

Tags: correlation, anova

I have lots of football result data, and I want to test the dependency of the number of goals per game on the weather (e.g. sun, rain, snow). I'm struggling to decide if the data is dependent or independent (and hence which ANOVA test to use). I can't be sure that every team will have played every other team more than once.

Comment: I assume that the weather data is categorical -- so you can just make a $\chi^2$ test.

Comment: @January No, a chi-square test is not best here. Even though weather is categorical, number of goals is not. So, a chi square test is, at best, underpowered. However, in addition, there is a dependent and independent variable, which chisquare does not capture.

Comment: @PeterFlom I would expect that most of the results (total goals in a match) are below 5, and that the relationship with weather might be very odd (e.g. bad weather -> extreme values; good weather -> average values). This is why personally I would start with a $\chi^2$. You are right about the dependence, though, but then, this could be checked separately.

Comment: If you had a hypothesis like the one you suggest (although I am not sure why you  would) you could check it by modifying the model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use *any* form of ANOVA since the number of goals per game is going to be a count, probably with a fairly small mean (I presume you are talking about what Americans call soccer, not what Americans call football).

Therefore, you need some sort of count regression model: Candidates could be Poisson, negative binomial and possibly zero-inflated variations of each of these.

Then comes the question of whether the data are dependent. This is a little tricky and we need to be clear about the difference between independent *data* and independent *variables*. However, here I would say they are dependent, since there are repeated measures on particular teams. This is clearer if you are interested in goals scored by each team than if you are interested in total goals by both teams.

Therefore, I think you need a nonlinear multilevel model.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Yes I mean soccer. That makes sense, but just so I understand the difference, suppose it was American football and instead of the total number of goals per game I was interested in the average number of goals per quarter. Is ANOVA now suitable (as the outcome is no longer a count)?

Comment: If you were interested in American football and interested in total number of points scored in a game, the range might be big enough to make an ANOVA reasonable, even if it's assumptions are not strictly met.